# impossible to create Colab notebooks with a GSuite account

Tags: google-workspace

I am the admin of Gsuite for my organisation, le lycée Merleau-Ponty in France. It’s a college (lycée en français).
I've installed colaboratory in gsuite applications with the market (i'm the admin for the domain lycee-merleauponty.fr), more than 24 hours, my users can't yet create notebooks.
When they access google drive with their gsuite account (for example, pierre@lycee-merleauponty.fr),
they can see the colaboratory link in the left menu but when they click on it and try to create a notebook, they got an error message (Google sign-in required connexion to google requested - you must be connected with a google account to continue). I can’t solve the problem and the gsuite support told me to find the answer in this place. Has someone encountered the same problem or has an idea about this issue ?
NB : several broswsers have been tested, private navigation, even tor browser.
I've got a few screen captures if needed.
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Apps > Additional Google Services > Access to additional services without individual control

Turn Service Status ON for Everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Educational OU of Colab users needs to have age access set to "all members are over 18" to allow the app to launch.